# Ionic 2 view rendering (and erroring) before data has chance to load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I'm writing my first Ionic 2 app and am struggling to get my head around something that I didn't have to worry about in Ionic 1.

I have a list view which lists items fetched from an API. This works fine. When you click on an item in the list view, you go to a detail view (which makes another ajax call to fetch additional details). This view renders before the ajax call has completed and I'm really not sure why.

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    http: any;
    baseUrl: String;
    apiKey: String;

    constructor(http:Http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8100/api';
        this.apiKey = 'xxx';
    }

    getList(token, page) {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/list?key=' + this.apiKey +  '&token=' + token + '&page=' + page + '&per_page=20')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    getDetails(token, ref) {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/details/' + ref + '?key=' + this.apiKey + '&token=' + token)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Problem page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { DataService } from '../../app/services/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'details',
    templateUrl: 'details.html'
})
export class DetailsPage {
    token: string;
    item: any;
    ref: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private dataService:DataService, private storage: Storage, public params:NavParams) {
        this.ref = params.get('ref');
    }

    getDetail(token, ref) {
        this.dataService.getDetails(token, ref).subscribe(
            data => {
                // this completes after the view has rendered, so the view errors
                this.item = data;
                console.log('this.item = ');
                console.log(this.item);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
                // handle expired token and redirect
            }
          );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('on init ran...');

        this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
            this.token =  val;
            this.getDetail(this.token, this.ref);
        });
    }
}
```

Every var in my template errors, for example, the first is:

```
Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
```

Am I missing something obvious or is there a better way to go about this? All the tutorials I find have the ajax call in the class and not in a service which can't be right...

--- edit ---

As requested here is the nav push from the list page:

```
viewDetailsPage(ref) {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {
        ref: ref
    })
}
```

--- edit 2 ---

As requested here is the list page template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Items</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="viewDetailsPage(item.reference)" icon-start>
            <h2>{{item.reference}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.type.title}}</p>
            <ion-badge item-end>{{item.status.title}}</ion-badge>
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and the details page template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Item</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
        <h4>{{item.reference}}</h4>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: How does your `navController.push()` call look like to open the `DetailsPage`?

Comment: Added to the question - thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is even possible with ionic2, when an item in the list is clicked, should I do the ajax call and then push all the data required in the details view to details view?

Comment: Whats the output of  `console.log(params.get('ref'))`?

Comment: Add `details.html` as well.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa `console.log(params.get('ref'))` returns the correct passed ref.

Comment: `details.html` @JamesJ.

Comment: Added both templates as requested.

Comment: Try changing `{{item.reference}}` to `{{item?.reference}}`

Comment: That did it! I didn't even know ? was a thing - do you have a doc link? Feel free to add an answer below and I'll accept - thank you! Would love to know why I have to do that in there and not in the list template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `{{item.reference}}` to `{{item?.reference}}`

or

`item: any = {}` instead of  `item: any`;

As view render before ajax call, it try to get `reference` property of `item`. Since `item` is still type of any and not object, it throw error.

`{{item?.reference}}` to handle asynchronous variables.

Comment: Changing `item: any = {}` fixes any template vars that are at the first level of the object but not any within nested objects. For example:

{{ item.reference }} <-- works fine
{{item.stats.color}} < still errors without using the `?` operator (which I'd rather avoid). Is there another type that covers nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

After not being able to find a single example anywhere of a "popped" page making ajax calls I ended up making the getDetail ajax call from the list page instead and passing the data to the details page like:

List page, when a list item is clicked:

```
viewDetailsPage(ref) {
    this.DataService. getDetails(this.token, ref).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.item = data;

            this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, {
                item: this.item
            })
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
            // handle expired token and redirect
        }
    );
}
```

Feels like this is the proper way of doing it though would love some confirmation of this.

---- update ----

whilst this works, I ended up going with the accepted answer.

Comment: It will cause delay in page change. Which is not good as per user experience. Your questions method is correct, but if you find nothing then at least show a loader during ajax call, otherwise user may keep clicking.